# Alamofire requests are slow

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire in my project, my problem is requests takes a long while to load (10 seconds at least), is there a way to speed it up? 
That's one of the requests I'm handling

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Alamofire.request(.GET, TripsEndPointURL, parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, JSONData, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else {
                TripsTableList = JSON(JSONData!)
                self.TripsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: @rshev done, I edited my answer

Comment: looks okay, check your connection with the server via postman or any other rest client.

Comment: I have another android application with the same api connections, its requests takes no longer than 2 seconds

Comment: Most probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277371/swift-uitableview-reloaddata-in-a-closure: UI updates must be done on the main thread.

Comment: @MartinR Nope, I've done that already

Comment: Hi Tareq, any solution on your end? I'm facing the same problem, android is much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Alamofire correctly. I'd imagine this is a problem with the server, or your connection. Try replacing the endpoint URL with the url of any small image, from a different server, just to experiment with downloading it. If it's still slow, it's your connection. If it's faster, it's the server.