# Firestore into TableView [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've already seen: [Swift UITableView reloadData in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277371/swift-uitableview-reloaddata-in-a-closure) but it still does not work. That's why I'm creating a new thread for this.

I'm trying to insert Firestore data into a custom tableview. But when I print the numbers it returns (In the console):

> "MyDogwalk.listTxt"

And no data is showing up on the tableview.

I guess all of this is relevant. (I also have 2 classes, with init etc)

```
class HistoryViewController: UIViewController {

    //Tableview
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    var list: [listTxt] = []


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        list = createArray()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func createArray() -> [listTxt]
    {
        var tempTxt: [listTxt] = []

        //Authentication
        let authentication = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        //Choosing collection
        db.collection("rastad").document(authentication!).collection("promenad").getDocuments()
            { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
                if err != nil
                {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(String(describing: err))");
                }
                else
                {
                    //For-loop
                    for _ in QuerySnapshot!.documents
                    {
                        self.list.removeAll()
                        let document = QuerySnapshot!.documents.first
                        let data = document!.data()
                        data.forEach { (item) in

                            let data1 = data["Dog"] as? String
                            let data2 = data["Person"] as? String
                            let data3 = data["What"] as? String
                            let data4 = data["Date"] as? String
                            let data5 = data["Time"] as? String


                            let txt = listTxt(dog: data1!, person: data2!, action: data3!, time: data4!, date: data5!)
                            print(txt)

                            tempTxt.append(txt)
                        }

                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }

        //return tempTxt
        return list
    }
}

extension HistoryViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let listPath = list[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell") as! HistoryCell

        cell.setCell(list: listPath)

        return cell
    }


}
```

And.. Why is this downvoted? I got an answer that was actually working for this case, and the question is detailed enough for people to understand, isn't it?

Comment: Reload your `tableView` in main queue.

Comment: @Dharmesh Where is the "main queue", im new to swift so im kind of lost haha

Comment: like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277371/swift-uitableview-reloaddata-in-a-closure

Comment: @Dharmesh Thanks a lot for your help, it's solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createArray()` method runs async code, and fills `tempTxt`. But you are returning `tempTxt` before async code has been run. So instead returning from `createArray` method and setting its value to `self.list`, just do it in the method itself:

```
self.list = tempTxt
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

---

You are iterating over `documents` but always using data of `documents.first`. Try this:

```
self.list.removeAll()

for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
  let data = document!.data()
  data.forEach { (item) in

  let data1 = data["Dog"] as? String
  let data2 = data["Person"] as? String
  let data3 = data["What"] as? String
  let data4 = data["Date"] as? String
  let data5 = data["Time"] as? String

  self.list.append(listTxt(dog: data1!, person: data2!, action: data3!, time: data4!, date: data5!))
  }
}

self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly fine!!! Thanks!! Only one problem tho, it displays the data like this: 

https://imgur.com/a/4guOcEB

It's only retrieving 1 of the rows, and makes a lot of duplicates. How do I solve that? Do you know? :)

Comment: I think the issue is in how you fill `tempTxt`. You have an unnecessary loop for example.

Comment: Do you mind edit the text and show a better example? :) Which loop is unnecessary? :)

Comment: Iterating over `documents` is unnecessary if you use `documents.first` always. Either remove loop or access each `document`. I updated the post

Answer (score 1):

Change `self.tableView.reloadData()` to

```
self.list = tempTxt
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And skip returning array from that func

Comment: You mean "return list" at the bottom?

Comment: Yes and change the func signature

Comment: I got the result in the tableview now, but only one problem tho, it displays the data like this: imgur.com/a/4guOcEB It's only retrieving 1 of the rows, and makes a lot of duplicates. How do I solve that? Do you know? :)

Comment: You should iterate over all documents and get the data, now you are only accessing the first document (`first()`)

Comment: Change outer loop to `for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents` and then skip the inner loop and just do `let data = document.data()` and then `let data1 = data["Dog"]` and so on

Comment: So I removed ".first" and also the inner loop. But getting this error now: https://imgur.com/a/cLaQMku

Comment: Ohh!!! I understand how to solve it! Now it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!!